# can I use glftpd's hash algorithm in php?

Tags: php, algorithm, hash, passwords

can I use glftpd's hash algorithm in php? How could I find that algorithm?

I think this snippet is what could lead me to the answer...

```
PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1(pwd, strlen(pwd), real_salt, SHA_SALT_LEN, 100, mdlen, md);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP >= 5.5 provides a native [hash_pbkdf2()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-pbkdf2.php) implementation of PBKDF2.

Comment: thanks! don't think there is a package of 5.5 for ubuntu server yet though, but that info wasn't in the original question.

Comment: There are 3rd party, well-known (but not official) 5.5 packages already exists for ubuntu: https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5 Also there is a native php-implementation exists in hash_pbkdf2() documentation's user comments.

Answer (score 1):

The [PHP-PasswordLib](https://github.com/ircmaxell/PHP-PasswordLib) library supports [PBKDF](https://github.com/ircmaxell/PHP-PasswordLib/blob/master/lib/PasswordLib/Password/Implementation/PBKDF.php).